# PySpark: filtering out RDD elements fails on 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to `filter` out elements of an RDD where the field 'status' is not equal to 'OK'. I create my RDD from a set of CSV files on HDFS, then use `map` to get the structure I want before trying to `filter`:

```
import csv, StringIO    

files = "/hdfs_path/*.csv"

fields = ["time", "status"]

dial = "excel"

default = {'status': 'OK', 'time': '2014-01-01  00:00:00'}

def loadRecord(line, fieldnames, dialect):
    input = StringIO.StringIO(line)
    reader = csv.DictReader(input, fieldnames = fieldnames, dialect = dialect)
    try:
        line = reader.next()
        if line is None:
            return default
        else:
            return line
    except:
        return default

harmonics = sc.textFile(files) \
              .map(lambda x: loadRecord(x, fields, dial)) \
              .filter(lambda x: "OK" not in x['status'])
```

I can do other things to this RDD -- e.g. another `map` to `get` only certain fields, etc. However, when I run my code with the `filter`, one of the tasks always fails with an exception in my `filter` lambda function:

```
'NoneType object is not iterable'
```

I thought this meant that the `filter` lambda was receiving a `None`, so I added code to `loadRecord` to avoid returning `None`. However, I still get the same error. It does work on a small sample dataset, but my actual data is large enough that I'm not sure how to detect which part(s) of it may be causing the problem.

Any input appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, relpace `map(lambda x: loadRecord(x, fields, dial))` with `map(lambda x: (x, loadRecord(x, fields, dial)))` - this way you save both original record and the parsed one.

Second, replace `filter()` call with `flatMap(test_function)` and define the `test_function` the way it tests the input and if the second passed parameter is None (parsed record) it whould return the first one.

This way you would get the input lines causing your problem and would test your script on them locally. And in general I would add a line `global default` as a first line of your `loadRecord` function

Comment: I implemented this with a `map` and a `checkNone` function that returned either the offending line or the default line. Then I ran a `filter` to remove all of the default lines. The final output contained 0 lines, which is interesting. Thanks for the ideas! I'll leave this open until tomorrow to see if there's any other input; if not, I'll accept your answer since it did allow me to get around the "None" exception.

Answer (score 0):

Using [0x0FFF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4205335/0x0fff)'s answer as a basis, I was able to get my code to run. I still haven't seen the offending line of the offending file, but I'm a lot closer than I was. Here's what I did, starting with the code in my question:

```
def checkNone(x):
    try:
        return "OK" not in x['status']
    except:
        return True

harmonics = sc.textFile(files) \
              .map(lambda x: loadRecord(x, fields, dial)) \
              .filter(lambda x: checkNone(x))
```

Comment: have you tried repartitioning the filtered harmonics, `harmonics = harmonics.repartition(numberleft)`